# CentOS: Insufficient space in download directory //var/cache/yum/base/packages Insufficient space in target directory

Tags: centos, centos5, yum, partition

`Error Downloading Packages:`
  `redhat-logos - 4.9.99-11.el5.centos.noarch: Insufficient space in download directory`
 `//var/cache/yum/base/packages to download`

Output from df -h
`/dev/sda2             3.9G  3.7G     0 100% /`
`/dev/sda11             17G  2.7G   13G  17% /extra`
`/dev/sda10            996M   44M  901M   5% /logs`
`/dev/sda9             2.0G  670M  1.2G  36% /applications1`

I also used yum clear all but nothing working. Please advice me.

the **YUM** directory is located in `/etc/yum` and `/etc` is mounted on `/`

Comment: Please don't create double posts for the same question, it won't get answered faster that way! (http://serverfault.com/questions/363146/root-file-system-is-full-and-i-need-to-install-additional-software)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `/` is full and you're in a bit of a pinch, you can move your cache directory to `/extra` with the `cachedir` directive in `/etc/yum.conf`.

Maybe something like:
`cachedir = /extra/yum/cache`

You'll need to recover space under `/`, though.  It's not going to be happy sitting at 100%.  I mean, you won't have any where to install those packages that Yum is having trouble caching.

Answer (score 1):

Look in `/var/cache/yum/`. That's where the yum transactional and temporary files are stored. Also try `yum clean all`.

Looking at your setup, it seems as though your `/` partition is a bit too small for your installation. A quick look at a new CentOS 6 install in my environment shows that about 3GB is necessary for the OS installation files. If you're not separating `/usr` into its own partition, you may want to triple or quadruple the amount of space you've allocated to `/`.

Comment: I used `yum clean all`. nothing worked.

Comment: How can I change/increase the size of `/`. I googled itbut I could not find any convincing answer. The machine is in production environment. I dont want to mess up anything on it.

Comment: @vinny, that's really a whole seperate question but you need to determine if you have any unallocated space left on the disk(s).